# What is the difference between table and external table in Netezza?

Tags: netezza

What is the difference between table and external table in Netezza? Does it always reads datafile in the backend after loading data is it required to again copy data from external table to normal database table?

Answer (score 4):

This is covered pretty well in lot of blogs and tech sites, like this one : http://tennysusantobi.blogspot.no/2012/08/netezza-external-tables.html

Basically external tables are just a definition residing in Netezza, allowing it to query data from (usually) local textfiles and not having to load them onto a database in netezza physically. Also used to export data easily (as covered in the link).

Answer (score 0):

Tables:
Both definition and data resides in databases. More precisely data is stored physically in each data slice based on distribution key.

External Table:
Only table definition resides in database but not the actual data. Data resides in file itself.
It is mainly used to load/ unload the data. It can also be used to backup netezza tables or to transfer data from one netezza box to another netezza box.